# Enable GPS on BQ Aquaris E4.5 ubuntu edition without accepting the Nokia HERE terms and conditions

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, gps

I have a BQ Aquaris E4.5 ubuntu edition and want to use GPS location. On first boot I decided not to accept the Nokia HERE terms and conditions, now GPS locations doesn't work. Does anybody know how to get GPS working for users that don't want to accept the Nokia HERE terms and conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPS will work without accepting Nokia HERE but it can take time for it to get a position.
Get the app [SensorsStatus](https://uappexplorer.com/app/me.yohanboniface.sensorsstatus) and put it in GPS mode and leave the phone on. Disable the screen lock (security settings) to keep the phone active. After a while the app will show your position.

This way you can know GPS is functioning and while this worked on my BQ Aquaris 4.5, some map apps do not.

Comment: The hint to be more patient did the trick (even without installing the app SensorStatus)! Waiting for GPS location while preventing screen lock (simply by touching the screen from time to time) and if this doesn't work turning GPS off and on again eventually makes GPS work on my BQ Aquaris 4.5 ubuntu edition without having accepted the Nokia HERE terms and conditions. Thanks!